# Add Controller Dialog: Filter down the list of Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When adding strongly types Views or Controllers every effing type present on my system is presented. There's no way to filter those like we can when choosing References?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **AutoComplete** set in that combo box.  So in other words, start typing in your desired Model Class into the combo box and you should be presented with autocomplete functionality.

This will eliminate the need for you to have to scroll to your desired Model.

Comment: Did try that without good results initially but I'll take a deeper dive. Thkx

Comment: See my response. The DDLs do not support autocomplete, altho that's a good idea.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com I should have clarified, I didn't mean autocomplete in the popular sense with a display of all matching elements.  Thanks for the clarification, Rick!!

Answer (score 1):

The Model class and Data context class DDL's do not support autocomplete. They do allow you to enter characters and select the DDL, the first match will be highlighted. For example on the Music Store Tutorial, on the Model class, you can enter 'c' and the select the drop down. Cart will be highlighted, followed by ChangePasswordModel, Country, CountryViewModel and all the rest.

Please visit [our UserVoice site](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc) and make a suggestion to add AutoComplete and a tool tip to suggest entering the the first few letters of the model.